# Строка пути на PHP

Tags: php

Привет всем.

Помогите составить функцию на php.

Имеется массив групп на сайте:

```
$groups_arr[id] = array('parent_id' => ХХХ, 'name' => ХХХ);
```

где id это id группы, parent_id - id группы родителя, name - имя группы.

Нужно составить функцию, которая бы возвращала массив начиная с текущей группы и до корневой группы. Массив нужен для составления строки пути и для подсветки групп, которые участвуют в пути.

Массив должен выглядеть так:

```
 array() {
  [1]
    array() {
      ["parent_id"] = 0
      ["name"] = Группа 1
    }
  [2]
    array() {
      ["parent_id"] = 1
      ["name"] = Подгруппа 1.1
    }
  [3]
    array() {
      ["parent_id"] = 2
      ["name"] = Подгруппа подгруппы 1.1.1
    }
  }
```

Пробовал что-то подобное,
вызывая `getTree($groups_arr, ТЕКУЩАЯ ПОДГРУППА)`:

```
function getTree($arr, $id) {
   $path = array();
   $path[] = array(id => $id, 'parent_id' => $arr[$id]['parent_id'], 'name' =>$arr[$id['name']);
   if ($arr[$id]['parent_id'] != 0) $path[] = getTree($arr, $arr[$id]['parent_id']);

   return $path;
}
```

Но получается массив не той структуры. Уже все перепробовал, подскажите, кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужен довольно простой алгоритм

```
текущая группа = Х
путь = [текущая группа]
пока у текущей группы есть родительская
  текущая группа = родительская группа
  подставить родительскую группу в начало пути
```

который реализуется меньше, чем за десять строчек

```
$currentGroupId = 3;
$currentGroup = $groups[$currentGroupId];
$path = array($currentGroup);
while ($parentGroupId = $currentGroup['parent_id']) {
    $parentGroup = $groups[$parentGroupId];
    $currentGroup = $parentGroup;
    array_unshift($path, $parentGroup);
}
```

Вроде все. Никаких проверок на целостность данных, предполагается, что у вас и так все в порядке.

upd. Если требуется сохранение ключа

```
$currentGroupId = 3;
$currentGroup = $groups[$currentGroupId];
$path = array($currentGroup);
while ($parentGroupId = $currentGroup['parent_id']) {
    $parentGroup = $groups[$parentGroupId];
    $currentGroup = $parentGroup;
    $path = array($parentGroupId => $parentGroup) + $path;
}
```

Comment: Хм, думал, что обычная мульти-сортирвка относительно `parent_id`. Невнимательный.

Comment: щас буду пробовать

Comment: супер, работает. только не соображу теперь как вывести в этот массив и текущую группу?